# more than one option value for a filter in a table js

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I hope you can give me a little help.
First of all: I'm not a trained programmer and I teach myself everything, but sometimes it's very tedious not to find a result for several days.

I am in the process of creating a list with filter options.
The following options:

```
    <select id="idTyp">
    <option value="all">Alle Typen</option>
    <option value="Pflanze">Pflanze</option>
    <option value="Feuer">Feuer</option>
    <option value="Wasser">Wasser</option>
    <option value="Elektro">Elektro</option>
    <option value="Psycho">Psycho</option>
    <option value="Kampf">Kampf</option>
    <option value="Finsternis">Finsternis</option>
    <option value="Metall">Metall</option>
    <option value="Fee">Fee</option>
    <option value="Drache">Drache</option>
    <option value="Farblos">Farblos</option>
    <option value="Trainer (I)" value="Trainer (A)">Trainer</option>
    <option value="Spezial-Energie">Spezial-Energie</option>
</select>

<select id="idSeltenheit">
    <option value="all">Alle Stufen</option>
    <option value="häufig">häufig</option>
    <option value="nicht so häufig">nicht so häufig</option>
    <option value="selten">selten</option>
    <option value="selten, holo">selten, holo</option>
    <option value="ultraselten">ultraselten</option>
    <option value="selten, holo GX">selten, holo GX</option>
    <option value="selten, prisma-stern">selten, prisma-stern</option>
    <option value="selten, regenbogen">selten, regenbogen</option>
    <option value="selten, geheim">selten, geheim</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="SearchData();" value="Filtern" />
```

Here is the corresponding JS:

```
const table = document.getElementById("cardListTable");
const tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

function SearchData() {

    var typ = document.getElementById("idTyp").value.toUpperCase();
    var seltenheit = document.getElementById("idSeltenheit").value.toUpperCase();

    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
        
        var rowTyp = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var rowSeltenheit = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[3].textContent.toUpperCase();
        var isDiplay = true;

        if (typ != 'ALL' && rowTyp != typ) {
            isDiplay = false;
        }
        if (seltenheit != 'ALL' && rowSeltenheit != seltenheit) {
            isDiplay = false;
        }

        if (isDiplay) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

My problem:
I would like to take this option

```
<option value="Trainer (I)" value="Trainer (A)">Trainer</option>
```

include multiple values.
There are the values ​​Trainer (I) , Trainer (A), Trainer (U), etc. and all should be displayed with the value "Trainer" at the same time.

What is the best way to do this?

I really hope for your help.
Many Thanks

Comment: the `option` cannot have multiple `value` attributes, store it as array, combine and split, or use  `data` attribute

Comment: Isn't there a way to write the code so that one column must contain the word "trainer"?

Comment: Can you include all three with a delimiter of some sort (",","|",etc), then take that delimiter into account in `SearchData()`?

Comment: @mykaf That would be exactly the solution. But how do I take this into account in the SearchData() ? (I'm sorry, I'm really a beginner. A tip would be helpful)

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to delve into your function, but I would split `typ` by your delimiter (turn it in to an array) and iterate over that...